# On MacOS Catalina with latest XCode, __DARWIN_C_LEVEL is too low for String.h... what should I do?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, macos-catalina, string.h

I'm starting a new job.  I'm a windows guy that has been working in the Microsoft stack for decades.  The new job calls for work to be done on a Mac, and I'll be working in straight C code.  It's interesting, and I vaguely remember using it a tiny amount in the mid-90s.  But I'm running into a problem.  When I try to compile the code ("make" command on the command line tool) it throws an error...

The codebase I'm learning is trying to use the `*strdup(const char *__s1)` function/method as defined in the string.h include file.  When I look at that header, I see where it *would* be defined, but there's a preprocessor if-block around it that looks like...

`#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= 200112L`

Looking around for that __DARWIN_C_LEVEL variable online... I see people asking what it is, but I haven't seen anything about what to do if your value is too low.  I tried looking for a way to alter a config file or something on my machine so that value would just be high enough, but I can't find that.  Is there something I need to update so that the code does what I want?

As an additional note, the only other guy at work that does anything in this code base works on a straight linux machine and edits the code with Vi.  He's obviously an expert in the code base and his environment, but doesn't know how to help with trying to get this running on MacOS.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit 9 November 2020

I'm beginning to believe I don't actually have the latest version of XCode if that would explain the issue.  I haven't gotten a response, but I'm asking about help with that piece here at work.

I'm also trying suggestions.  When I try the option for std=gnu11...

```
make -std=gnu11
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- =
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- g
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- u
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 1
```

If I remove the equal sign, it seems to like it better but still has errors...

```
make -std gnu11
[...]
No implicit rule found for 'gnu11'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'gnu11'.
Must remake target 'gnu11'.
make: *** No rule to make target `gnu11'.  Stop.
```

Comment: It might help to know which compiler you're using and which C dialect.  (-std=c11 or similar)

Comment: This is a guess, but try adding `-std=gnu11` to your compilation options. If that doesn't work by itself, try adding `-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` as well. If either of those works say so and I will explain.

Comment: I'll give away just how much of a newbie I am to MacOS... how do I check what C dialect I'm using?  And for the suggestion of the command parameters... those would be done on the make command?

Comment: @zwol, those command params didn’t work.  Errors around invalid options.

Comment: That's bizarre. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @zwol, it's whatever compiler installed with the current version of xcode, and then when I open a terminal to the directory of the project, I just type "make" and hit enter.  As a side note, `-std=gnu11` threw an error until I replaced the equal sign with a space, and then it got past the command, but the compile didn't work.  I'm sorry if I'm being obtuse about something.  This is just not my skill set.

Comment: Could you please edit into your question (1) the _complete and unedited_ text of the error message you get when you use `-std=gnu11`, and (2) the _complete and unedited_ text of the output of the command `cc --version`.  I suspect you have misunderstood what the error message means; if I can see exactly what it said, maybe I can figure out what's really wrong.

Comment: (Did you know that you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design, SO doesn't seem interested in fixing it.)

Comment: @Kevin Try `make CC='cc -std=gnu11'` exactly as shown including all punctuation.